# Login and Registration page validation in android

Tags: java, android, database

I have developed one login form and Registration form in Android. I have used validation here till only login form. I have to fill anyone (username or password) then my app should display Success! and should move to other activity.

But, if both fields are empty, the success message should not be displayed and it should display Login fail!!!.

Please help me this..

```
if(status.equals("Success!"))
    {
        // ADD  to save  and  read next time
        String strUserName = mEditText1.getText().toString().trim();
        String strPassword = mEditText2.getText().toString().trim();
        if (null == strUserName || strUserName.length() == 0)
        {
            // showToast("Enter Your Name");
            mEditText1.setError( "username is required!" );
            boolean isUserValidated = false;
        }
        if (null == strPassword || strPassword.length() == 0)
        {
            // showToast("Enter Your Password");
            //isPasswordValidated = false;
            mEditText2.setError( "password is required!" );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this condition true? ``status.equals("Success!")``

Comment: if(strUserName .isempty) condition to check empty or blank.

Comment: ok I check it...

Comment: @PraveenRawat that doesn't fix anything, considering he's already checking the string length

Answer (score 1):

Something like below?

```
if (etEmail.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            tilEmail.setError(getString(R.string.validation_input_email));
            etEmail.requestFocus();
        } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(etEmail.getText().toString().trim()).matches()) {
            tilEmail.setError(getString(R.string.validation_input_email_invalid));
            etEmail.requestFocus();
        } else if (etPassword.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            tilPassword.setError(getString(R.string.validation_input_password));
            etPassword.requestFocus();
        } else {
          //Call your API/function here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for validation.

```
//Call on button action 
if (validate())
   hitLogInAPI();


/**
 * Validate all cases of input fields before api hit.
 */
private Boolean validate() {
//email empty check.
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etEmail.getText().toString())) {
    //Error Toast 
    etEmail.requestFocus();
    return false;
}
//valid email check.
else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(etEmail.getText().toString().trim()).matches()) {
    //Error Toast
    etEmail.requestFocus();
    return false;
}
//password empty check.
else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
    //Error Toast
    etPassword.requestFocus();
    return false;
}

//password range check.
else if (etPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() < 6
        || etPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() > 32) {
    //Error Toast
    etPassword.requestFocus();
    return false;
}
return true;}
```